# How to copy and modify a single line from a buffer?

Tags: replace, string

I want to write a function that copies the current line from a buffer, but transforms it before in certain way. Specifically, I need to generate file names depending from lines of code. For example, having this line of C code:

```c
    __asm__ volatile (".rept 200\n\t"
              "sub r5, r4, #255\n\t"|     // <---- point is the bar
              
              ".endr\n\t"
```

I want to have in my kill-ring/clipboard the string

```
sub_r5_r4_255.csv
```

I came up with this very ugly solution:

```lisp
(defun my--get-instruction-csv-id ()
  "Generate a file .csv id from current line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (move-beginning-of-line nil)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (move-end-of-line nil)
    (kill-ring-save nil nil t))
  (let ((old-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (yank)
      (replace-regexp " " "_" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (replace-regexp "," "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (replace-regexp "#" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (replace-regexp "\\\\t" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (replace-regexp "\\\\n" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (replace-regexp "\"" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (move-end-of-line nil)
      (insert ".csv")
      (print (buffer-string))      ;(kill-new
      )))
```

(where in the last line `kill-new` has been substituded by `print` for debug purposes).
However, I recognize this is **inefficient and non idiomatic**. **How can I improve it?**

For example, Emacs tells me I should replace `replace-regexp` with `re-search-forward` and `replace-match`: should I do that with a `while` loop? Is there an equivalent non regexp function that I can use? Can I avoid killing + yanking from the C buffer?

Comment: You should certainly avoid killing and yanking just to get your hands on a string. Doing `(buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (point))` would get you the current line (up to where `point` is - if you want the whole line, replace the `(point)` call with `(line-end-position)`) as a string that you can `insert` into your temp buffer instead of `yank`ing.  I'm sure you'll get more suggestions for the rest as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for `line-beginning-position` and `line-end-position` but I couldn't find them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, so I'll start the ball rolling. I would certainly replace the killing+yanking as I mentioned in my comment. For the rest, I would use the string manipulation library [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) which you can install as a package from MELPA.

This library provides a convenient `s-replace-all` function that can do all of the little replacements in a single call. Here is a function along these lines:

```el
(defun my--get-instruction-csv-id ()
  "Generate a file .csv id from current line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((s (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (point))))
    (kill-new
      (s-append ".csv"
        (s-replace-all '(("\"" . "") ("," . "") ("#" . "") ("\\n" . "") ("\\t" . "") (" " . "_"))
                       (s-trim s))))))
```

So we save the buffer substring between the position of the beginning of the line and the current point, use `s-trim` to trim whitespace from both ends of the string, use `s-replace-all` with a list of replacements (which can be augmented if necessary), append the suffix and pass the result to `kill-new`.

Since we are not moving point or changing buffers, there is no need for `save-excursion` either.